# Iterating through a vector of tuples c+17 style don't work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, code-readability, structured-bindings

I am currently looking neat ways in which i can iterate this vector of tuples..

This is what I am currently doing?

```
#include <experimental/filesystems>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::tuple<std::experimental::filesystem::path, std::experimental::filesystem::file_status, std::size_t>
file_info(const std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry &entry)
{

    const std::experimental::filesystem::file_status fs(std::experimental::filesystem::status(entry));
    return {entry.path(),
                fs,
                std::experimental::filesystem::is_regular_file(fs) ? std::experimental::filesystem::file_size(entry.path()) : 0u};

}



int main ()
{
    std::experimental::filesystem::path _path(string_dir_to_test_files);  // string_dir_to_test_files is just a string 
    std::experimental::filesystem::directory_entry dir_path(_path);
    if (std::experimental::filesystem::exists(_path))
    {
        std::cout << "exists() = " << std::experimental::filesystem::exists(_path) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Number of files in directory: " << number_of_files(_path) << std::endl;
        std::vector<std::tuple<std::experimental::filesystem::path,std::experimental::filesystem::file_status, std::size_t>> items;
        std::transform(std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(_path),{},back_inserter(items),file_info);
        for( auto const& index : items)
        {
            std::cout << std::get<0>(index) << std::endl; // This line could be written better?
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No data to build database with!" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Even though it does the job, it does not seem to be "reader" friendly, is there other ways in which I can the iterate the elements of the vector, in a more reader friendly manner?

One way I tried to make the for loop a bit more readable was by making like this:

```
for (auto const& [path, status, size] : items) {
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
}
```

But this somehow give me this error:

```
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp: In constructor ‘database::database()’:
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:25: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
         for(auto const& [path, status, size] : items)
                         ^
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:25: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:26: error: ‘path’ was not declared in this scope
         for(auto const& [path, status, size] : items)
                          ^~~~
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:26: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/experimental/filesystem:39:0,
                 from /home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.h:9,
                 from /home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/experimental/bits/fs_path.h:79:9: note:   ‘std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path’
   class path
         ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/experimental/bits/fs_path.h:79:9: note:   ‘std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path’
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:32: error: ‘status’ was not declared in this scope
         for(auto const& [path, status, size] : items)
                                ^~~~~~
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:32: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/experimental/filesystem:41:0,
                 from /home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.h:9,
                 from /home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/experimental/bits/fs_ops.h:274:15: note:   ‘std::experimental::filesystem::v1::status’
   file_status status(const path& __p, error_code& __ec) noexcept;
               ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/experimental/bits/fs_ops.h:274:15: note:   ‘std::experimental::filesystem::v1::status’
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:40: error: capture by copy of incomplete type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’
         for(auto const& [path, status, size] : items)
                                        ^~~~
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp: In lambda function:
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:46: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘:’ token
         for(auto const& [path, status, size] : items)
                                              ^
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp: In constructor ‘database::database()’:
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘:’ token
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
/home/noob/soundcloud/src/include/database/database.cpp:31:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘:’ token
make[2]: *** [src/include/database/CMakeFiles/database.dir/database.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/include/database/CMakeFiles/database.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: How about `using` that long thing called "std::experimental::filesystem" for a start?

Comment: I don't like to `using` a namespace, but you could do a namespace alias: `namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;`

Comment: Instead of a tuple, you may create dedicated struct, then you just have `index.path` instead of `std::get<0>(index)`

Comment: It is not `std::cout << std::get<0>(index) << std::endl;` which is the less readable IMO.
`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is much too broad for Stack Overflow, which deals with more focused coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, consider [codereview.se] instead - but do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!.

Comment: I changed the post to become more question like.  @TobySpeight

Comment: solution upgrade gcc to v7.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++17, you may do:

```
for (auto const& [path, status, size] : items) {
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that.. But some ending with an compile error?

https://pastebin.com/pnEYmNQU

Comment: Solution: upgrade gcc to v7.0

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 you may do

```
for (auto const& tup : items)
    std::experimental::filesystem::path path;
    std::tie(path, std::ignore, std::ignore) = tup;
    std::cout << path << std::endl;
}
```